# .NET using wrong 2.0 machine.config instead of 4.0

Tags: .net, iis-7, machine.config

I have a .NET web application install on IIS 7.0 Windows Server 2008 R1.  I have installed .NET 4.0 on the server and configured an app pool for 4.0 and integrated pipeline.  For some reason I am getting the following error:

```
(500.19) The configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot be read because
  it is missing a section declaration.
```

It appears that it is using the wrong `machine.config` file from V2.0 .NET rather than the `machine.config` file which has defined the `system.web.extensions` config section.  I proved this by replacing the `machine.config` file in the V2.0 framework with the one from the V4.0 framework and the web application no longer throws the `500.19` error.  I have tried to uninstall and reinstall .NET 4.0 as well as running `aspnet_regiis -i`.

Any thoughts on why it would be trying to using the 2.0 `machine.config`?

Comment: have you run `aspnet_regiis -iru` to register ASP.NET 4 with IIS?

Comment: I hadn't tried those parameters, but I just did and still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, that it's realy reason/solution, but last thing I've try it is (in IIS Manager):

1. Navigate to server in right panel (root node)
2. In the features list open "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions"
3. There is 2 items with descriptions ASP.NET v4.0.30319 with restrictions set to Deny
4. Set restrictions value to Allowed

This is last thing i've tried before issue is gone.