# The configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

I am getting error (**The configuration section `system.web.extensions` cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration**) while installing my Web Application in **Server 2008 32 bit machine** with **.NET Framework 4.0**. but it works well in 2008 r2 64 bit machine.

This is my webconfig file info

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Any idea to get rid of this error?

**Note**: I have checked all the related entries in Stack over flow but nothing was useful for me

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The issue resolved for me after adding the following configuration setting in my webconfig file

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

We can refer this article for more info: http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/11/The-configuration-section-system-web-extensions-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-missing-a-section-declaration.html

Comment: In my case, I didn't use scriptResourceHandler or jsonSerialization in my web.config and including the sections above caused the issue to continue.

Answer (score 77):

Try changing the application pool run time from .net 2.0 to .net 4.0

Comment: The default .NET version when I created a new app pool, in 2017, is .NET 2.0, from 2002. I can only imagine why.

Comment: Thank you for this. I recently downgraded .NET framework from 4.8 to 4.7.2, and when I removed 4.8 from the system, IIS decided to downgrade all my app pools. When I re-installed 4.7.2, it didn't set them back to the correct version. So your comment led me down the right path.

Answer (score 8):

I also had the same problem after upgrading my OS from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2 , I just changed the application pool settings to .NetFramework 4.0.0 and also changed the classic to Integrated mode ... my problems solved ..

Answer (score 2):

Probably related question: [.NET using wrong 2.0 machine.config instead of 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360011/net-using-wrong-2-0-machine-config-instead-of-4-0). I've experienced similar issue... And solution for me:

Not sure, that it's realy reason/solution, but last thing I've try it is (in IIS Manager):

1. Navigate to server in right panel (root node)
2. In the features list open "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions"
3. There is 2 items with descriptions ASP.NET v4.0.30319 with restrictions set to Deny
4. Set restrictions value to Allowed

This is last thing i've tried before issue is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Note down .netFramework version v4... (examplev4.0.030319)  you have installed 
Edit your application pool to correct .NET Framework v4..

Good luck

-Satish

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

I tried this and it works good for me.  Maybe helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

For me, changing the **application pool .NET Framework version from v2.0 to v4.0** solved this issue.

Open **IIS** --> Select **App Pools** --> **Select App Pool** from list --> From context menu select **Basic Settings...** --> **Change .NET Frame version to v4.0**