# Umbraco CMS: Manual Installation

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, windows-vista

I am using Windows Vista Ultimate and I want to install Umbraco CMS, with which I have no previous experience. 
Common installation methods i.e. Installing either via Microsoft Webmatrix or Web Platform Installer didn't work for me. The former is for 7 and 8 versions of Windows and the latter downloads all installation files but fails to install. That is it shows "Installing ..." dialog for over 3 hours that makes me to forcefully end the installation. So all efforts have to be done from scratch (including download of the installation components using Web Platform Installer). 
Is there a way to manually install Umbraco without the help of Platform Installer? I have downloaded seperately the files needed for Vista(e.g. Umbraco 7xxx.zip,Powershell 2, ASP.NET MVC, etc.). I don't see any executable in the package for Umbraco. There are just DLL's which I don't know where to copy to, as well as many aspx and ascx files that I don't know what to do with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases shows the latest and all other  available umbraco releases.

Under the 'Current' heading, you will find links to the [most recent stable release detail page](http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/703) where you can grab  UmbracoCms.X.X.X.zip which are all the files you need to go through the process manually.

One of the absolute best things about umbraco is that it's so easy to spin up a new isntall this way!

*Important!* Before you unzip - be sure to right-click the .zip file and open the properties page.
There will be an option to "Unblock" - be sure to click this or you may well experience issues with the dlls.

Unzip these files to where your webroot will be, set-up your IIS site and open in your browser - umbraco will automatically pick up that you need to do 'the install' and take you through a few simple steps that set-up the database and your admin credentials. There are no exe's or installer files - it's all embedded, more-or-less, in the site.
A good practice is the remove the [/install/] folder once you've gone through these steps.
Umbraco has some [installation documentation here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/) if you want to see all the various ways and steps available to install an umbraco site. -I prefer the .zip way described above, but you can also go the NuGet route too.

Comment: Thanks. I finally did the installation. Maybe the problem was that the installer assumes, by default, IIS Express and not IIS. This time I chose IIS in options sections before proceeding to installation (within Windows Platform Installer). But I still have problem <br> `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.` more details at [link](http://codepad.org/AsEB3kpG)

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit machine?
Perhaps this will help get over that last hump : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20066794/2150286

Comment: Yes I use a Pentium IV, 32 bit machine. I'm really newbie to .NET and I might have to install Windows 7 and then try automatic installation to make this work and errors go.

Comment: I'd take win7 over vista for sure, that aside - you'll still find the same issue regardless. This is top of my head - but i believe your issues comes from the differences in your machine.config (the IIS analog to web.config).  "system.web.extensions" is in my machine.config but not in yours -- this means that you need to declare it in your web.config.

Comment: (cutoff,sorry) You should be able to copy the code from the linked answer and paste inside your <configSections> section.
Also, be sure that you have all the .net framework dependencies in place (3.5 / 4.0 - if you're installing umbraco7, you will need .net 4.5)
I'd encourage updating to windows7 as, one,it's just a way better OS compared to vista - but it may also eliminate a ton of rare corner-cases as most everyone else, including the Umbraco HQ developers, are probably running the more up-to-date OS. p.IV huh?? ;)

Comment: That's too complicated! I also copied that code section you said and pasted into my web.config file. But I still had problem. `HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46878/discussion-between-pc-pdx-and-misaq)